Enabling Screen Sharing without Control Center
I have disabled Control Center by moving ControlCenter app to a different location, but due to that I am not able to share screen on Safari on Ventura as well as Sonoma during Google Meet, or on any other website that supports screen sharing, but as soon as I enable Control Center by moving back Control Center app to its correct location, it starts working.
How can I just enable screen sharing without enabling Control Center as I don't want the user to change WiFi, Bluetooth, Sound etc settings.

Is this something that can be done in Terminal?
